# DB2 Select column names from nested select

Tags: sql, db2-400

I was trying to select columns from sys columns lib, but function LISTAGG returns only a varchar which then gets listed instead of listing columns returned by nested select

```
  SELECT (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',')
            FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE' AND COLUMN_TEXT LIKE '%Date%'
            GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
    FROM subsystem.MYTABLE
```

is there a way to cast this subselect result to type which can be then selected?
or some other way to reach same result

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but not in a single statement like you are trying to do.

You'll need two statements with one of them being an "dynamic" statement that gets
prepared.  Normally, it'd be `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` but since you want to return the data, you'll also need a cursor.

The statements will also need to be imbedded into a application program, SQL stored procedure or function.

```
create or replace procedure mylib.rtnDates()
result sets 1
language sql
begin
    declare myColList varchar(1000);
    declare mySqlStmtText varchar(3000);
    declare returnDates cursor with return to client for mySqlStmt;
    
    -- note neither group by nor FETCH FIRST 1 ROW is needed
    -- if you limit the select to a single table in a single schema
    -- which is probably what you need
    SELECT  LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') into myColList
      FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE' AND COLUMN_TEXT LIKE '%Date%'
            and table_schema = 'MYLIB';
    
    set mySqlStmtText = 'select ' concat myColList concat ' from mylib.mytable';
    
    prepare mySqlStmt from mySqlStmtText;
    open  returnDates;
end;

call mylib.rtnDates();
```